# Efficient way to preload images, in all browsers, using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Building a webapp, and for any user's first visit to the site, after the main page is loaded and displayed, I then want to pre-load 11 images of about 50 KB each, so user is not waiting for them when app needs to display them later.

Purpose of this is only to get them in the browser's cache, from off the network - as users might be on phones, and using even just 2G mobile connections potentially. Preloading has to be done after main page is fully loaded and displayed, and also I want the preloaded images to be loaded sequentially, not asynchronously as they are used in order one at a time, so want the first ones in the sequence to be available soonest.

I'm thinking to use something like:

```
var img = new Image();

$(window).on('load', function() { preload_images(1); });

function preload_images(index) {
        if(index < 11) {
            img.onload = function() {
                preload_images(index + 1);
            }
            img.src = 'path_to_my_images/imagenum'+index+'.png';
}
```

So basically I want the browser to be using as little memory as possible, hence reusing the same image definition. I don't need to use the images at this stage, just get the browser to pull them off the network and into cache. When they are actually used the images will be referenced as a background image as I'm using them for sprites (so each image has many sprites on it which I'm accessing via CSS offset), and will be referenced by their original full URL, which I assume would pull them from browser cache?

Alternative I suppose is to create an image element in the DOM and repeatedly change the src attribute but will the onload event still work with that?

Any gotchas with the above or is there a better way of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: Creating a new image takes a minuscule amount of memory, and doesn't matter, so you might as well create a new image for every iteration, as right now the source of the image is changed before the image loads.

Comment: I'm not sure about the minuscule memory - although the PNGs are around 50K each, the dimensions are 220 X 2450 pixels X 24 bits = 1.6 MB each unpacked by my calculations. And this is going to be loading on various mobile phones (i.e. lower end ones too) in their browser, while users are running other apps. Hence why I need to load sequentially. To be honest I don't want to load at all, just seems to be the only way to get into the browser cache off the network. I don't see a problem with image source - the code should set the URL, image loads, then ...

Comment: ... onload reset the onload function and change the source again to load the next image, etc...? Thanks

Comment: My point was that you should move the definition of `var img` inside the function, and create a `new Image` for each image, and not reuse the same one. You're still going to load all the image, but creating a new image takes up a very small amount of memory, there's no need to reuse the variable, and by doing so you change the `img` variable before the `onload` handler fires.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks. Sorry if I'm missing the obvious, but I don't understand your point about changing the source before the image loads. It looks like it already does this, as the browser doesn't load the image until the src is set, after the onload function is reset each time. I'm assuming setting a new src loads the new src into cache, even if the src is already set to URL of the previous image. Setting onload before ensures that image doesn't load without the trigger for the next image load being set. Correct me if I'm wrong! Thanks